# как в ruby on rails задать условие для определенно поля у всплывающего списка select во вьюхе

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Помогите, пожалуйста, с одной проблемой. У меня есть всплывающий список, но мне нужно для одного из полей сделать 2 условия.
По сути перекинуть это условие check_box

```
- if policy(@callcenter).activate_trial?
  = f.check_box :trial_mode, disabled: !@trial_mode_allowed, custom: :switch
```

на поле trail, которое у меня есть в enum у status(enum status: [:active, :trial, :suspended, :blocked])

```
= f.select :status, t_enum_for_select(Callcenter, :statuses)
```

И еще кое-что, одно из полей нужно сделать недоступным для выбора, но оно должно отображаться в списке, потому что оно приходит по api из другого приложения и устанавливается в нем автоматически

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Методом проб и ошибок я все-таки смог решить проблему, сложность была в том, что ни одного похожего примера не нашел

```
= f.select :account_status, t_enum_for_select(Callcenter, :account_statuses),
                            disabled: ['suspended', ('trial' if !@trial_mode_allowed || policy(@callcenter).activate_trial?)]
```